# Can this simple graph exist?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

My question is can the following exist as a simple graph? Or is it not possible?

*The graph is to have 7 vertices and 7 edges and is connected. Also, if **any one** of its edges is removed, it will not disconnect the graph.*

My thought is that it does not exist (purely based on 'try and error'), but I am having trouble explaining the reason in words.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: A cycle perhaps?

Comment: I believe it would have to contain a cycle to satisfy the last condition

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the hint given by user113102... The cycle $C_7$ satisfies all of your conditions.

Comment: sorry, I am a little confused. What do you mean by C7?

Comment: The [cycle graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) with seven vertices.  It is a graph with a single cycle.  A "triangle" is $C_3$.  A "square" is $C_4$, etc...

Comment: That being said, you are correct that the last condition implies that your graph must contain a cycle (*though not necessarily that it must be a cycle graph*), but you could have gotten that from the fact that the number of edges is at least as large as the number of vertices, implying the graph cannot be a tree or a forest.  That being said, you should be able to make an argument based on degrees that the average degree of each vertex is $2$, and that if there happened to be any vertex of degree $1$ that the last condition would be violated, implying all degrees *must be* identically $2$.

Comment: All of this together will imply that the *only* graph satisfying all of your conditions is in fact the cycle graph $C_7$.

Comment: Right. Of Course! Thanks for clarifying, and apologies for my misunderstanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\sum\limits_{v\in V}\deg(v) = 2|E|$ by the handshaking lemma, we get that the average degree of each vertex must be $2$.

As the removal of any edge will not disconnect the graph we get that $\delta(G)> 1$ as otherwise a degree $1$ vertex could be disconnected from the graph by removing it's sole edge.

These two facts together imply that the graph must in fact be $2$-[regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph).  The *only* $2$-regular connected graphs possible are the [cycle-graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph).

We learn then that the only graph possible which matches your stated conditions (connected, 7 vertices, 7 edges, and edge-connectivity at least $2$) is going to be the graph $C_7$.

[image: The graph C_7]

(*image from wolfram mathworld*)

Answer (score 0):

If the graph is connected, it has atleast one spanning tree which will contain $6$ of the $7$ edges of the graph. The $7^{\text{th}}$ edge is a chord, meaning that the graph has only one (fundamental) circuit. Removal of the branches of the tree that are not part of this fundamental circuit will disconnect the graph. Thus, the only way to uphold the last condition is for all branches to participate in the fundamental circuit, giving you the circuit of length $7$.